# Android - Is widget already on homescreen? Is alarm running?

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager

I am trying to make a widget, where its update frequency can be defined by user and changed at runtime. I can do that using alarm manager, however, *is there a way to change the interval of the alarm once its set?*

If not, I can still cancel it and start it again with new interval, however I dont know how will this work because widget might not even be added to the homescreen, so the question is, *is there a way to know if an alarm is running **or better, widget is on homescreen?***

Thanks

// EDIT
**How to determine if your widget exists**

```
private boolean widgetExists() {
    ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(this, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this).getAppWidgetIds(myWidget);
    return ids.length > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to change the interval of the alarm once its set?

For this one, we can reference the docs for `AlarmManager.setRepeating()`:

> Schedule a repeating alarm... If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled.

In other words, setting an alarm with the same type cancels the existing interval and resets the alarm with the new values.

---

> is there a way to know if an alarm is running or better, widget is on homescreen?

This is the job of `AppWidgetProvider`.  The callbacks in your provider (`onEnabled`, `onUpdate`, etc.) can be used to determine the state of whether any widgets are actually active ([AppWidgetProvider docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html)).

Comment: +Alarm, thanks, thats cool, I thought I would have two alarms running. +Widget .. I still dont get how would I determine from activity, wether there is an widget on homescreen, maybe query something to get those IDs you get as parameter in onUpdate for example?

Comment: The enabled/disabled callbacks will be where you get notified when all widgets ar either added or removed.  As far as providing this data to other parts of your app, the provider will need to maintain this state so it can be queried from other components in your app (this is not done for you), either in memory or persisted somewhere like SharedPreferences.

Comment: yea, that was plan B, I wondered if there was an easier way, okay thanks !

Comment: Another option to use from an external class would be to use AppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders() to iterate over all the current widgets on the device and look for one whose .provider field matches you.  Not sure that's more efficient though.